# Memory management in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, .net-3.5

I have to load multiple result sets (as DataTables) into memory via a C# script/code. Then, I will read each of these results and combine the relevant columns (as per rules) into a txt file. There is no certainty on how big the data set will be or how many tables will have to be handled. My script will simply see which tables to get data from and then store them in memory for processing.

The worst case could be that I run out of memory. So, is there a simple way I can page a resultset to the harddisk and extract it in parts ? Is there a better way to do what I am trying ?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of reading the entire result set at once, why don't you just modify your SQL query to bring back the data in manageable chunks?

Comment: Also, what is your programming background? You're calling C# a script and something, perhaps methods, tasks. There's a lot you can potentially do in C# to deal with this, but it can get complicated.

Comment: the problem is that there could be several tables spread across different servers (i know that there are 7 tables already). So, if I do joins, the query will become too long and even slow. Also, getting data of each table in chunks would require some conditions. I don't know what those conditions are for future tables. This might sound too much, but that is how it is.

Comment: @Magus - Thanks. I edited my question to make it more like a C# question. Actually, I will be making C# code to do data transfer inside an ETL tool (SSIS). But, I did not use that tag because it is more of a C# question.

Comment: I assume some of your colleagues specialize in SQL; you might ask if any of them have any pointers for improving your query. Ultimately, a slow query should be less dangerous than trying to run a process that may run you out of memory. That is particularly true considering querying is the database's very reason for existing.

Comment: @Magus - I am mostly on my own and it was even suggested that I avoid joins and such because it will get pretty complicated. Hence, I am thinking of the C# approach. Is this something for a C# programmer who is between beginner and intermediate ?

Comment: Again, C# is really not the place to be manipulating this scale of data. That's why databases exist. If you intend to use this much data, you should learn the kind of SQL required to use it well. Just like coding a UI in Assembly is possible but requires you to consider a whole lot of extra problems that you probably don't need to know about, C# dealing with this kind of data is a poor fit.